# How to save UserName from current user in other table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

i'm developing in Asp.Net MVC 4,I have the UserProfile table with following fields:

```
        public class UserProfile
        {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int UserId { get; set; }
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            public string UserType { get; set; } //flag de tipo usuário musico ou ouvinte  
        }
```

My application is simple,only to upload musics to database,each User only can upload your music.
At music field I have these fields:

```
    public class Musica
{
    public int MusicaId { get; set; }
    public int GeneroId { get; set; } //GenreID
    public int UserId { get; set; } //Needs to take the username from current user logged in app
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string NomeArtista { get; set; }
    public Genero genero { get; set; }
    public decimal Preco { get; set; }
}
```

This is my table relationship at SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Musicas] (
    [MusicaId]  INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [GeneroId]  INT             NOT NULL,
    [UserId]  INT               NOT NULL,
    [Nome]      NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [Preco]     MONEY           NULL,
    [NomeArtista] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,   
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Musicas] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MusicaId] ASC), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Musicas_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [UserProfile]([UserId])
```

**When a user**, will create your music at view, `i want to take the UserName from User and put on field UserName at Music table`, how can i do this?

I think that it's simple to do, but i don't know how to take the UserName from user and save at other table, anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
string currentUserName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Get some info about the user...

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(currentUserName...);
//    ....
```

Optionally...

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
string userName = user.UserName;
```

Comment: Assuming you are using a MembershipProvider for your user management and Forms Authentication.  If you are using ad, use the first example then user the AD API to lookup stuff about them from active directory with LDAP queries.

If you are using CLAIMS Authentication then use the first example and then w/e you used to supply users to claims authentication.

Comment: Sure, I'll put it on my create method? At musicController

Comment: Hi @Ryios i'm trying to do what you talk to me, but it's not working, this is my create method: http://pastebin.com/qtte3avx
I can take the UserName, but when db.saveChanges() is called the following error is displayed: `"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Nome', table 'aspnet-TestTcc2-20140907134144.dbo.Musicas'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated."` Could you help me?

Comment: That error seems to be for the `[Nome]` column in your `dbo.Musicas` table, not the `UserProfile` table's `Name`.

Comment: What kind of authentication is your site using?  Is it forms auth?  Is a Membership Provider configured in the web.config?  If so, then you also need to make sure the user is logged in.  If the user is anonymously accessing the site then you can't get their user name.  They have to log in first.

You can use HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated to determine if the user is logged in or anonymous.  If it's anonymous disable stuff that requires login.

Comment: Hey @Ryios sorry by delay! I'm using the default authentication from MVC 4. I run the debug, with your second example, I can get the username from current user, but i can't add the name in database, i think that have a problem with my create method(have a pastebin in my last comment) could you take a look?